# Unable to connect to an Azure Cosmos database via VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to connect to an Azure Cosmos DB and I see the error below:

[image]

I am able to open this database in the Portal, but not able to connect via VS Code.

Comment: Please edit your question to include more details (such as the protocol you chose for your Cosmos DB account). Also please include a text version of the error message, along with any other details related to this.

Comment: Try to log out and re-login, on my side it seems no problem.